# Link to one component from another from the same router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-router, router-outlet

I have multiple router outlets in my Angular 5 app.

One of them looks like this:

```
  {
    path: "admin",
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "/admin/(admin:news)",
        pathMatch: "full"
      },
      {
        path: "news",
        component: NewsComponent,
        outlet: 'admin'
      },
      {
        path: "new-post",
        component: CreatePostComponent,
        outlet: 'admin'
      }
    ]
```

I want to create link from NewsComponent to CreatePostComponent (`/admin/(admin:news)` => `/admin/(admin:new-post)`:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {admin:'new-post'}}]">Add Post</a>
```

But this is trying to create path `/admin/(admin:news)/(admin:new-post)` (instead of `/admin/(admin:new-post)`.

How should i do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `routerLink` is creating a relative path.

From the documentation: [Router Link Description](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description)

`If the first segment begins with /, the router will look up the route from the root of the app.`

`If the first segment begins with ./, or doesn't begin with a slash, the router will instead look in the children of the current activated route.`

You can add `/admin/` in front of the `outlets` to get the desired path.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/admin/', {outlets: {admin:['new-post']}}]">Add Post</a>
```